# how to turn this code into a function working code?

Tags: python

so i have some code that works perfectly without a function. But i want to change this inside a function, but it does not work properly.

For example, i have the `end=""`. This doesn't work in a function, without using `print`.

I also have more than one `print statements`. When i turn these to `return`, they don't work. So could someone please help me change this code to work in a function?

Thanks!

**My code**

```py
def underscore_hash_staircase(number):
    if number > 0:
        k = 2 * number - 2
        for i in range(0, number):
            for j in range(number-1, k):
                print(end=" ".replace(" ", "_"))
            k = k - 1
            for j in range(0, i + 1):
                print("#", end="")
            print("")
    else:
        number = int(str(number).replace("-", ""))
        i = number
        while i >= 1:
            j = number
            while j > i:
                print('', end=' '.replace(" ", "_"))
                j -= 1
            k = 1
            while k <= i:
                print('#', end='')
                k += 1
            print()
            i -= 1
            
print(underscore_hash_staircase(8))
```

so the code above doesn't work properly in a function, without the `print` statements. Please let me know how to get this working in a function without the print statements. Using returns. It should be exact output as what is being returned in this not function-working code.

Thanks again!

Comment: A function can only return once... Replace the `print`s with a string-building, and `return` that string in the end...

Comment: What is `print(end=" ".replace(" ", "_"))` intended to do? You're not printing anything, and `end=" ".replace(" ", "_")` is the same as `end="_"`

Comment: `number = int(str(number).replace("-", ""))` is the same as just `number = -number`

Comment: `print` isn't a statement, it's a built-in function and `end` is an optional keyword argument that it accepts when you _call_ it. It also doesn't return a value, so returning what a call to it returns makes no sense.

Comment: a suggestion is to use meaningful variable names as to not get confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should append to a string instead of printing, and then return the string. Append `\n` to add a newline.

```
def underscore_hash_staircase(number):
    result = ""
    if number > 0:
        k = 2 * number - 2
        for i in range(0, number):
           for j in range(number-1, k):
                result += "_"
           k = k - 1
           for j in range(0, i + 1):
               result += "#"
           result += "\n"
    else:
        number = -number
        i = number
        while i >= 1:
            j = number
            while j > i:
                result += "_"
                j -= 1
            k = 1
            while k <= i:
                result += "#"
                k += 1
            result += "\n"
            i -= 1
    return result

print(underscore_hash_staircase(8))
```

You also don't need all those inner loops. You can repeat a string by multiplying it.

```
def underscore_hash_staircase(number):
    result = ""
    if number > 0:
        k = 2 * number - 2
        for i in range(1, number + 1):
           result += "_" * (number - i)
           result += "#" * i
           result += "\n"
    else:
        number = -number
        for i in range(number, 0, -1):
            result += "_" * (number - i)
            result += "#" * i
            result += "\n"
    return result

print(underscore_hash_staircase(8))
print(underscore_hash_staircase(-8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a function can only return one value, instead of printing, you want to add to a variable to return instead of printing. Try:

```py
def underscore_hash_staircase(number):
    returnValue = ""  # start as empty string

    if number > 0:
        k = 2 * number - 2
        for i in range(0, number):
            for j in range(number-1, k):
                returnValue += "_"
            k = k - 1
            for j in range(0, i + 1):
                returnValue += "#"
            returnValue += "\n"  # adding a new line
    else:
        number = int(str(number).replace("-", ""))
        i = number
        while i >= 1:
            j = number
            while j > i:
                returnValue += "_"
                j -= 1
            k = 1
            while k <= i:
                returnValue += "#"
                k += 1
            returnValue += "\n"
            i -= 1
            
print(underscore_hash_staircase(8))
```

Edit: missed a print when replacing